# Realtek rtl8723e not working at Kernel 3.5

Tags: wireless, realtek, make

I have a problem with my Realtek wifi card.

Last time when using Kernel 3.2, all I have to do is punch in these codes while connecting to internet, everything will be solved. These codes are:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
wget -O- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK`/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz | tar -xz
cd rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012
make
make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723e
```

Now, with kernel 3.5, it gives an error at the 'make' command

```
make
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-44-generic/build M=/home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-44-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
/home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [/home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/*censored*/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-44-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I knew there's an update, but I'm not sure how to implement it, or how to get it. I tried to search for solution but to no avail. I tried make clean, and that doesn't solve my problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first posting of a newer version supposedly from a Realtek technician was available at:

```
wget -O- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz
```

but Jan 2014 that is no longer present.  Google for the file name for other copies (The important part is the "007.0809.2012" which is a date, so ignore any with earlier dates.

Or just upgrade to 13.04 or later, those work out of the box with the 8723.

Comment: Error 404: file not found.